# What am I doing wrong? I made an animation of exploding my cement block sprite and it works but the problem is that the animation doesn't go through

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I made an animation to explode my cement block sprites when their health is zero and it works but the problem is that it only works for the first cement block sprite I shoot and kill not all the cement block sprites in the `debris_group`. What am I doing wrong?

My exploding animation code is in the update function in my debris class and where I call it is in my player class collision function.

My code:

```
import random
import pygame
import pygame.freetype

pygame.init()

#screen settings
WIDTH = 1000
HEIGHT = 400

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("AutoPilot")
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

#fps
FPS = 120
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#load images
bg = pygame.image.load('background/street.png').convert_alpha() # background
bullets = pygame.image.load('car/bullet.png').convert_alpha()
debris_img = pygame.image.load('debris/cement.png')

#define game variables
shoot = False

#player class
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, scale, speed):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.bullet = pygame.image.load('car/bullet.png').convert_alpha()
        self.bullet_list = []
        self.speed = speed
        #self.x = x
        #self.y = y
        self.moving = True
        self.frame = 0
        self.flip = False
        self.direction = 0
        self.score = 0

        #load car
        self.images = []
        img = pygame.image.load('car/car.png').convert_alpha()
        img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (int(img.get_width()) * scale, (int(img.get_height()) * scale)))
        self.images.append(img)
        self.image = self.images[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.update_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.movingLeft = False
        self.movingRight = False
        self.rect.x = 465
        self.rect.y = 325

    #draw car to screen
    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery))

    #move car
    def move(self):
        #reset the movement variables
        dx = 0
        dy = 0

        #moving variables
        if self.movingLeft and self.rect.x > 33:
            dx -= self.speed
            self.flip = True
            self.direction = -1
        if self.movingRight and self.rect.x < 900:
            dx += self.speed
            self.flip = False
            self.direction = 1

        #update rectangle position
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy

    #shoot
    def shoot(self):
        bullet = Bullet(self.rect.centerx + 18, self.rect.y + 30, self.direction)
        bullet_group.add(bullet)

    #check collision
    def collision(self, debris_group):
        for debris in debris_group:
            if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(debris, bullet_group, True):
                debris.health -= 1
                if debris.health <= 0:
                    d.is_destroyed = True
                    self.score += 1
                    debris.kill()

    #player stats
    def stats(self):
        myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 30)
        scoretext = myfont.render("Score: " + str(self.score), 1, (0,0,0))
        screen.blit(scoretext, (100,10))

#bullet class
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, direction):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.speed = 5
        self.image = bullets
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x,y)
        self.direction = direction

    def update(self):
        self.rect.centery -= self.speed
        #check if bullet has gone off screen
        if self.rect.centery < 1:
            self.kill()

#debris class
class Debris(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,scale,speed):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.scale = scale
        self.x = random.randrange(100,800)
        self.speed_y = 10
        self.y = 15
        self.speed = speed
        self.vy = 0
        self.on_ground = True
        self.move = True
        self.health = 4
        self.max_health = self.health
        self.alive = True
        self.velocity = random.randrange(1,2)
        self.speed_x = random.randrange(-3,3)
        self.moving_down = True
        self.is_destroyed = False

        #load debris
        self.image = debris_img
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(100, 800)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-150, -100)
        self.rect.center = (self.x,self.y)

        #load explosion
        self.img_explosion_00 = pygame.image.load('explosion/0.png').convert_alpha()
        self.img_explosion_00 = pygame.transform.scale(self.img_explosion_00, (self.img_explosion_00.get_width() * 2,
                                                                               self.img_explosion_00.get_height() * 2))
        self.img_explosion_01 = pygame.image.load('explosion/1.png').convert_alpha()
        self.img_explosion_01 = pygame.transform.scale(self.img_explosion_01, (self.img_explosion_01.get_width() * 2,
                                                                               self.img_explosion_01.get_height() * 2))
        self.img_explosion_02 = pygame.image.load('explosion/2.png').convert_alpha()
        self.img_explosion_02 = pygame.transform.scale(self.img_explosion_02, (self.img_explosion_02.get_width() * 2,
                                                                               self.img_explosion_02.get_height() * 2))
        self.img_explosion_03 = pygame.image.load('explosion/3.png').convert_alpha()
        self.img_explosion_03 = pygame.transform.scale(self.img_explosion_03, (self.img_explosion_03.get_width() * 2,
                                                                               self.img_explosion_03.get_height() * 2))
        #explosion list
        self.anim_explosion = [self.img_explosion_00,
                               self.img_explosion_01,
                               self.img_explosion_02,
                               self.img_explosion_03]
        self.anim_index = 0
        self.frame_len = 3


    #spawn new debris
    def spawn_new_debris(self):
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(100, 800)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-150, -100)
        self.velocity = random.randrange(1, 2)
        self.speed_x = random.randrange(-3, 3)

    #respawn debris when they go of the screen
    def boundaries(self):
        if self.rect.left > WIDTH + 10 or self.rect.right < -10 or self.rect.top > HEIGHT + 10:
            self.spawn_new_debris()

    #update image
    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.velocity
        self.rect.x += self.speed_x
        self.boundaries()
        if self.is_destroyed:
            max_index = len(self.anim_explosion) - 1
            if self.anim_index > max_index:
                self.kill()
            else:
                if self.frame_len == 0:
                    self.image = self.anim_explosion[self.anim_index]
                    self.anim_index += 1
                    self.frame_len = 3
                else:
                    self.frame_len -= 1

    #make debris fall down
    def falldown(self):
        self.rect.centery += self.velocity
        if self.moving_down and self.rect.y > 350:
            self.kill()

######################CAR/DEBRIS##########################

player = Player(1,5)

##########################################################

#groups
bullet_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
debris_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

for x in range(50):
    d = Debris(1, 5)
    debris_group.add(d)
    all_sprites.add(d)

#game runs here
run = True
while run:

    #draw street
    screen.blit(bg, [0, 0])

    #update groups
    bullet_group.update()
    bullet_group.draw(screen)

    debris_group.update()
    debris_group.draw(screen)

    #draw car
    player.draw()
    player.move()
    player.collision(debris_group)
    player.stats()

    #update all sprites
    all_sprites.update()
    all_sprites.draw(screen)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        #check if key is down
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                player.movingLeft = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player.movingRight = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                player.shoot()
                shoot = True

        #check if key is up
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                player.movingLeft = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player.movingRight = False

    #update the display
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Why do you call `debris.kill()` in `Player.collision`? It is killed in `Debris.update` after the animation.

Comment: phshshshshhhhhhh. Cause I'm dumb..... Brother I almost punched my Mac and the answer was in my face the whole time..... Lol thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not `kill` the `debris` object in the `Player.collision` method. It is killed in `Debris.update` after the animation:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def collision(self, debris_group):
        for debris in debris_group:
           
            if debris.health <= 0:              # <--- already exploding
                continue            

            if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(debris, bullet_group, True):
                debris.health -= 1
                if debris.health <= 0:
                    debris.is_destroyed = True  # <--- `debris` isnstead of `d`
                    self.score += 1
                    # debris.kill()             # <--- DELETE
```

Comment: @J.R.BEATS See the answer. `debris.is_destroyed = True` instead of `d.is_destroyed = True`

Comment: @J.R.BEATS Note, you don't need the `is_destroyed` attribute at all. Use `if self.health <= 0` instead.

Comment: @J.R.BEATS How do you know it's 93? Did you count them?

Comment: @J.R.BEATS Likely 1 `debirs` is counted more than once. This happens when it is hit during the exploding animation. Avoid this with `if debris.health <= 0:` `continue`. (See the answer)